# Use of copyrighted material for creating a commercial product

Tags: copyright

In a hypothetical scenario, Mr. Peter writes a book about tree types in a certain geographical area. He creates a commercial products. Can he use another commercial product that is copyrighted, e.g. a map of a location (the map is a political map and has nothing to do with trees), for his tree research purposes, if such a map won't be part of the book he works on?

jurisdiction: EU country

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking here.

Comment: "Can he use another commercial product..." that is the question here. The question is written in formal English, all input information is provided. The question is clear.

Comment: If the answer to this question were "no" then most commerce would be impossible.  And there would be no market for books about how to run a business because the only people who would be able to read them would be people who aren't running businesses.

Comment: No books at all. "Sorry Ms Rowling but Everybody Poops is copyrighted and you read it while writing Harry Potter."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can he use another commercial product that is copyrighted, e.g. a map
> of a location (the map is a political map and has nothing to do with
> trees), for his tree research purposes, if such a map won't be part of
> the book he works on?

Yes.

Copyright protects particular expressions of ideas and knowledge, not the ideas and knowledge themselves.

Using a map for research purposes when the map or a modified version of it does not appear in the final work does not make the final work a "derivative work" covered by copyright.